# Rename a bunch of files on mac

Tags: python, linux, macos

I would like to rename a bunch of files on mac, and I was wondering if there was a utility to do this or if I needed to step into something like python. Here is the rename I'd like to do:

[image]

I want to zfill so the number is in the form of `\d{3}`, i.e., `GM008.mp3`. Is there a way within mac to do this, or what might be the quickest approach? What I'm currently doing is a one-liner in python:

```
[os.rename(src, './GM' + src.split('GM')[1].split('.')[0].zfill(3) + '.mp3') for src in os.listdir('.')]
# ['GM001.mp3', 'GM000.mp3', 'GM003.mp3', 'GM007.mp3', 'GM006.mp3', 'GM012.mp3', 'GM004.mp3', 'GM005.mp3', 'GM008.mp3', 'GM009.mp3', etc...]
```

Comment: `os` is the best choice with `os.rename(src, tgt)` - I do not have mac but it should be the good choice.

Comment: Given your current approach that you've just shared, what is the problem? Does it work? Do you need it to be more efficient? Also, it's a waste of memory to use a list comp if you're just tossing the list away and you only need `os.rename` for its side effect.

Comment: @ggorlen was just wondering if I can do it without using python. I.e., if there was perhaps a way within os (or even unix) to do a rename on a batch of files without some form of scripting it. I've found a "batch rename" in OSX but as far as I've found, it doesn't support regex.

Comment: Oh, OK--so, no Python. That wasn't really obvious to me from your original question.

Answer (score 2):

This should be pretty safe; we're looking for an exact match on your mp3 format `GM\d+\.mp3` and pad out the digit run before the `.mp3` with zeros using `zfill`. `os` is platform agnostic.

```
import os
import re

for fname in [x for x in os.listdir(".") if re.fullmatch(r"GM\d+\.mp3", x)]:
    os.rename(fname, re.sub(r"(\d+)(?=\.mp3)", lambda x: x.group(1).zfill(3), fname))
```

Comment: out of curiosity, do you know if it's possible to do a zfill using regex-only? I've tried a bit and I don't think it's possible in a single regex (you can do something like 2 OR 3, but not something like 1, or 2, or 3 digits).

Comment: No, you'd need a callback for the regex that checks the length and performs the pad like I'm doing here. The problem is that regex has no notion of counting, so it's unclear what substitute construct could be sensitive to arbitrary lengths (unless some engines offer such a thing). If you're only padding to 3 digits so you could enumerate that with multiple substitutions, but I assume that's not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT*** - After correcting your question my answer might not be the most useful but I hope it gets you to play with Automator :)

You can try things like `Automator` in Mac or `Apple Script`. `Automator` is built-in and you can record your workflow and translate it into a "script". It's very easy to use - kind of drag and drop.

When staring automator choose Aplication and then se up following:

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: @Krzystztof_K -- thanks, could you show an example of how to do that with the above?

Comment: Please let me know if folder has other types of files, if you are only looking for .mp3? Plese specify as much as possible...

Comment: @Krzystztof_K -- thanks for this, but actually you don't even need automator for that, the bulk rename is available directly in Finder. But as you can see it doesn't support zfill (try entering in "001"), so just this approach shown here wouldn't work. Oh actually I see a "make all numbers [ ] digits long...that might work."

Comment: @David542 No worries, give it a try! You can create "Service" ( when creating new Automator document type) and then just select all files, right click and choose your "Service" from context menu. Quicker than running python script.

Comment: @Krysztof_K I tried it and it doesn't seem like there's support for regex (at least with the finder commands). Your approach just renames them starting from 1, but what if the item starts with GM004?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the right place for this question, but in any case the following script will work for the exact format you've given. It should be easy to generalize this to work with slightly different names. `cd` into the directory with the files and run this script:

```py
import os

for filename in os.listdir("."):
    if filename.endswith(".mp3"):
        without_prefix = filename[:-4]
        # In this case, prefix = 'GM', num = the number
        prefix, num = without_prefix[:2], without_prefix[2:]
        new_name = f'{prefix}{num.zfill(3)}.mp3'
        os.rename(filename, new_name)
```